# Organizing service responsibilities

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I am creating a RESTful web service and I need to map the methods that I want to expose as paths. I got one question regarding the organization of service classes.

Is it normal to create one service class that is the endpoint of the application which internally delegates to other service classes?

And how do you organize methods and paths belonging to a resource? Do you create one MyClassCrudService class, one MyClassOperationsService class etc? And then add that path mapping annotations on each class, or do you create one MyClassResourceService class?

I find it hard to divide the service methods in different classes, and naming them properly.

I could need some guidance on how it is normal to organize the services.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend starting with one Resource class per logical resource and only adding complexity when necessary. Definining necessary really just takes experience and developing a personal taste or team standard.

If you're new to REST, I would also recommend [Bill Burke's RESTful Java with JAX-RS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596158041).

Comment: So one service for each resource such as CarResourceService, and then have all methods belonging to the car inside it?

Comment: CarResourceService would have methods that map to each of the HTTP methods that you want your RESTful API to support. Perhaps edit your question with a code example if that isn't clear?

Comment: Yeah, you create the service like that, but do you have the actual logic such as interacting with a third party web service to get something in this service, or do you delegate the actions in the CarResourceService to more specialized classes?

Comment: No, I would not include that in the JAX-RS Resource. I would think of the Resource as a view and keep business logic and data access elsewhere.